# boost multi index access to hashed unique index

Tags: c++, boost, lru, boost-multi-index

This code is adopted from the boost multi-index "mru" example:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/example/serialization.cpp

I have code that is doing something similiar as a boost::unordered_map, but I would really like to add the mru functionality from this example.

I would like to make this code work as close to having a boost::unordered_map as possible. The key feature for me is the [] operator of the unordered_map.

The final lines of main() are broken and above each line as a comment is my question.

Thanks in advance to all answers comments.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

class my_struct {
public:
    my_struct(int in_a, std::string in_b) : a(in_a), b(in_b) {}

    int a;
    std::string b;

    bool operator==(const my_struct &rhs) const
    {
        return (a == rhs.a);
    }
    bool operator!=(const my_struct &rhs) const
    {
            return !(*this == rhs);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const my_struct&ms);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, my_struct &ms)
{
    out << ms.a << " " << ms.b << std::endl;
    return out;
}

inline std::size_t
hash_value(const my_struct &val)
{
    return boost::hash_value(val.a);
}

// tags for multi_index
struct umap {};
template <typename Item>
class mru_list
{
  typedef multi_index_container<
    Item,
    indexed_by<
      sequenced<>,
      hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<umap>, identity<Item> >
    >
  > item_list;

public:

  typedef Item                         item_type;
  typedef typename item_list::iterator iterator;

  mru_list(std::size_t max_num_items_):max_num_items(max_num_items_){}

  void insert(const item_type& item)
  {
    std::pair<iterator,bool> p=il.push_front(item);

    if(!p.second){                     /* duplicate item */
      il.relocate(il.begin(),p.first); /* put in front */
    }
    else if(il.size()>max_num_items){  /* keep the length <= max_num_items */
      il.pop_back();
    }
  }

  iterator begin(){return il.begin();}
  iterator end(){return il.end();}

//private:
  item_list   il;
  std::size_t max_num_items;
};

int main()
{
    mru_list<my_struct> mru(10);
    my_struct one(1, "One");

    mru.insert(one);
    mru.insert(my_struct(2, "Two"));
    mru.insert(my_struct(3, "Three"));
    mru.insert(one);

    std::cout<<"most recently entered terms:"<<std::endl;
    for (mru_list<my_struct>::iterator itr = mru.begin(); itr != mru.end(); ++itr) {
        std::cout << itr->a << std::endl;
    }

    // what is my return type?
    mru.il.get<umap>();

    // Why doesn't this work?
    mru_list<my_struct>::iterator itr = mru.il.get<umap>().find(one);

    // Why doesn't this have a [] operator like boost:unordered_map
    mru.il.get<umap>()[1] = "foobar";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is related to your problem, but you declare your friend operator as taking a `const mystruct&`, but your definition takes a `mystruct&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // what is my return type?
>
> ```
> mru.il.get<umap>();
> ```

Its return type is the type of your `umap` index, which is:

```
  typedef typename boost::multi_index::index<
        item_list
      , umap
      >::type hashed_index_t;

  mru_list<my_struct>::hashed_index_t& hashed_index = mru.il.get<umap>();
```

In C++11 it is easier with `auto`:

```
  auto& hashed_index = mru.il.get<umap>();
```

> // Why doesn't this work?
>
> ```
> mru_list<my_struct>::iterator itr = mru.il.get<umap>().find(one);
> ```

`find()` returns an iterator of `umap` (second) index and the above statement is assigning it to the iterator of the first index. There are [projection operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection) to convert from one index iterator type to another iterator type of the same multi-index container, e.g.:

```
mru_list<my_struct>::iterator itr = project<0>(mru.il, hashed_index.find(one));
```

> // Why doesn't this have a [] operator like boost:unordered_map

Can't say why, [it just doesn't](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/hash_indices.html).